# Setting up Sunspot for Production without Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, ubuntu, solr, sunspot

For the past few days I've been trying to move my Rails app into production mode, but I hit a block, where Sunspot does not want to move into production.

I've seen in multiple places that you should use a standalone **Solr** installation and run it behind **Tomcat**, but through the 20 or so tutorials I've tried I've been unable to get it to work properly - I get 404's for all **Solr** requests in my log/production.log.

Is there any way at all to have pure sunspot running in production? If it is extremely hacky and bad practice, I don't mind - I just want it to run without having to go through the pain of all these external installs again.

One thing I tried was switching my config/sunspot.yml to look like this:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/development
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

Though this didn't seem to work. This type of solution seems promising--tricking sunspot into thinking it is running in production mode, when it is really using a development solr instance.

**Information on server setup:** 2 rails apps, one in the document root (www.bla.com is one app) and another in a subURI (www.bla.com/my-broken-search-app). I'm using Phusion Passenger with Apache on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't give enough information，I can only provide a solution maybe fit for your problem。Since Tomcat by default runs on port number 8080,you should change your  `config/sunspot.yml` file to

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8080
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/development
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5
```

However there is high chance get a port conflict with others program. Sometime we just need to change the Tomcat port number.Get more information on how to change tomcat port on [How to change Tomcat default port ?](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/%22How%20to%20change%20Tomcat%20default%20port%20?%22)